# Bazel cross compile of tensorflow for ARM fails

Tags: python, tensorflow, arm, bazel, zynq

I am trying to build tensorflow to run on a Zynq, specifically, the Z7020.  I have petalinux running on the board, and python 3.4.9.  When trying to build tensorflow following the instructions found here:[https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_raspbian#cross-compiling_from_sources]
Note that both petalinux and raspbian are both Debian derivatives and the Z7020 has the same CortexA9 cores as the raspberry-pi 0 and 1 series boards.

I am trying to build on an Ubuntu 16.04 host.  The command I am using to build is:

```
sudo CI_DOCKER_EXTRA_PARAMS="-e CI_BUILD_PYTHON=python3 -e CROSSTOOL_PYTHON_INCLUDE=/home/rklein/Python-3.4.9/Include" tensorflow/tools/ci_build/ci_build.sh PI-PYTHON3 tensorflow/tools/ci_build/pi/build_raspberry_pi.sh PI_ONE
```

Bazel churns for about 2 hours and comes back with the following error message:

```
    /home/rklein/tensorflow/bazel-ci_build-cache/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/eab0--lots of hex digits--85e8/external/arm_compiler/bin/arm-linux-gnueablhf-gcc --lots of options

    In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:8:0, from ./tensorflow/python/lib/core/bfloat16.h:19, 
                     from tensorflow/python/lib/core/bfloat16.h:18:
                     from /usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:13:54: 
    fatal error: arm-linux-gnueabihf/python2.7/pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
    #include <arm-linux-gnueabihf/python2.7/pyconfig.h>
                                                       ^
    compilation terminated.
```

What settings are needed to tell Bazel to use python3?  Note that there is no /usr/include/python2.7 directory on the host machine, so I suspect that Basel is doing some voodoo behind the scenes.  The command

```
find ~ -name python2.7
```

comes up empty.

I have tried to read up as much as I can on Bazel, but the documentation seems pretty lean - any good references would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help you with your error message (or Bazel altogether). However I installed TensorFlow on an Xilinx Zynq Ultrascale+ with a Petalinux kernel and an Ubuntu (arm64) root filesystem. It's not the same exact chip (but the installation process should be similar). I didn't build TensorFlow myself, instead I used the packages provided by the [tensorflow-on-arm](https://github.com/lhelontra/tensorflow-on-arm/releases) project. Maybe my experience will be useful for other people to get TensorFlow running:

1. You need a working OS (Xilinx has documentation for that). Depending on your chip you need either a 32 (armhf) or 64 Bit (arm64) rootfs. I used an Ubuntu rootfs, so I could use apt-install.
2. You need to install some dependencies. I followed the instructions from the [tensorflow-on-arm](https://github.com/lhelontra/tensorflow-on-arm) project.
   `apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk automake autoconf curl zip unzip libtool swig libpng12-dev zlib1g-dev pkg-config git g++ wget xz-utils`
3. You also need Python (be sure to install Python v3.5 - not Python v3.6, etc.).
   `apt-get install python3-numpy python3-dev python3-pip python3-mock`
4. I also needed to install two not listed packages.
   `apt-get install cython3 libhdf5-dev`
5. Install some pip3 packages (you might want to install those in a virtual-environment and also update pip3).
   `pip3 install -U --user keras_applications==1.0.5 --no-deps`
   `pip3 install -U --user keras_preprocessing==1.0.3 --no-deps`
   `pip3 install -U --user numpy grpcio h5py`
6. Now you should download the TensorFlow pip package. The different packages are listed under [Releases](https://github.com/lhelontra/tensorflow-on-arm/releases). I chose TensorFlow v.1.12 for Python v3.5 and arm64 / aarch64.
   `wget https://github.com/lhelontra/tensorflow-on-arm/releases/download/v1.12.0/tensorflow-1.12.0-cp35-none-linux_aarch64.whl`
7. Now you can install the package with pip3.
   `pip3 install -U --user tensorflow-1.12.0*`

I hope it worked for you!

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Can you tell me how you ran an ubuntu disk image on a peta-linux kernel??  How can you ensure correctness between the two distributions?  I am assuming you created a bitstream for the Xilinx board that frankensteined the two distros together.  How did you do that?  Any details would be appreciated.  Thanks,

Comment: I pretty much followed this [tutorial](https://medium.com/developments-and-implementations-on-zynq-7000-ap/install-ubuntu-16-04-lts-on-zynq-zc702-using-petalinux-2016-4-e1da902eaff7). In Short: First I create a Kernel with petalinux. I put the created files BOOT.BIN and image.ub in the BOOT partition of my SD card. Then I put the rootfs (from the tutorial) in a second partition. As much as I know it is a customized Ubuntu core rootfs. [Xilinx](https://xilinx-wiki.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/A/pages/18841732/Ubuntu+on+Zynq) has some information about it, too.

Comment: I can't tell you how correct this process is. However, for my little project it worked quite well. My biggest problem was the transition from an ARM 32 Bit to 64 Bit rootfs (I used the Zynq Ultrascale+, but most tutorials are written for the Zynq 7000). For me the big advantage was, that I could use apt-get afterwards. Out of curiosity: What was your solution for the last months?

Comment: I remain unable to solve this problem.  Specifically, I do need to be able to rebuild tensor flow for an ARM system, not use someone else's.  I can't get anyone from google/tensorflow to respond on this.  But being able to run someone else's ARM port on the Xilinx Zynq UltraScale helps me quite a bit.  Many thanks for the pointer to the tutorial.  The ability to use apt-get is huge.

Comment: After a bunch of research I have concluded that cross compiling tensor flow for ARM is (or at least was) broken.  The only way to get an ARM port is to natively compile.  The problem, of course, is the huge number of dependencies that Bazel brings, that all need to be available or built for the target platform.  So trying to do this on a constrained ARM platform is somewhere between hard and impossible.